# Elegant way to make sure string is no longer than a given length

Tags: java, string, java-8

I want to know if there is a quicker and/or more elegant way to achieve this with Java 8.
I would like to have a string no longer than a max length (say 4 character max)

```
input "" -> ""
input null -> null
input abc -> abc
input abcde -> abcd

some function (string s){
     if(s==null)
          return null;
     if(s.length()>4)
          return s.substring(1,4);
     return s;
 }
```

Comment: `return (s != null && s.length() > 3) ? s.substring(0, 4) : s;`

Comment: This code is simple and elegant enough, not sure what you're aiming for... The only thing I'd change is to return only in the last line.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you should add that as an answer.

Comment: **make sure string is always same length** well, what you did does not ensure that. It does encure that string wont be longer then 4 chars.

Comment: You have a mistake in `s.substring(1,4)`.  It should be `s.substring(0,4)`, otherwise your code is fine.  The code by Elliott Frisch may look better to you but that is only a question of style.  And his code also has a mistake that would be better as `s.length() > 4`.

Comment: @lucasvw Not an answer because it's not using any Java 8-ness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is not `null`, you can always take a substring between `0` and the minimum between `4` and the length of the string. Couple this with Java 8's [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), and you can do this in single statement:

```
private static String noMoreThanFour(String str) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
                   .map(s -> s.substring(0, Math.min(4, s.length())))
                   .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: i like this solution!, but there is no guarantee that string is not null,

Comment: @user648026 the `ofNullable` clause handles this.  Giving a `null` input to this method will produce a `null` result, as required.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind pulling in an external dependency, Apache Commons StringUtils is full of handy helper methods that do exactly this kind of thing, including a null/length safe SubString.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring(java.lang.String, int)

I personally find with pure Java projects it is almost always beneficial to make use of Apache Commons for the myriad of helpers.

The above said, your code is easily readable, so I wouldn't go out of your way to change it.

Comment: Well, if you decide to use commons-lang3, you can use `StringUtils.truncate(input, maxLength)` directly.

Answer (score 2):

1 less return statement keeping if-else structure

```
if(s==null || s.length()<=4){
     return s;
}else return s.substring(0,4);
```

another stem would be to use conditional expression, but it wont be more readable

```
return (s==null || s.length()<=4)? s:s.substring(0,4)
```